# I need to completely 'wp_dequeue_script'; what's the best way?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

One of my WordPress templates is **completely different** and requires different css and js (but still needs needs the core JQuery as well as the bootstrap 3 css/js).

So, how would I go about removing the generic style.css and also a few other css files (and js files) that are site wide? I think that it is a variation of the below?

I'm new to WP!

```
  // Unique Page Template
  if (is_page_template(specific-template.php')):
  //  Remove Site-wide CSS
  wp_dequeue_style('generic styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.2');
  // And this would enqueue the unique css
  wp_enqueue_style( 'unque to this template css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/unique-to-this-template.css', array(), '1.0');
  endif;
```

Is my logic correct here?

Thanks for all direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is basically correct. You're just missing a `'` in your wp_dequeue_style() function.

Also, `wp_dequeue_style()` only accepts one argument: the handle of the script/style you want to dequeue. You don't need to pass the url. So your code would need to look like:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'specific-template.php' ) ) {
    //  Remove Site-wide CSS
    wp_dequeue_style( 'generic styles' );
    // And this would enqueue the unique css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unque to this template css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/unique-to-this-template.css', array(), '1.0');
}
```

You'll also need to make sure that this code is hooked *after* the original style is enqueued.

If this is all your CSS from the same theme though (and not a child theme), then I'd suggest a different approach: Rather than dequeueing a specific style, just selectively enqueue it:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'specific-template.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unque to this template css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/unique-to-this-template.css', array(), '1.0' );
} else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'generic styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.2' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you Remove and Add Site-wide CSS then remove if condition.

```
    if (is_page_template(specific-template.php')):
    endif;
```